# Changing elements at the top of an Adapter without repositioning lower items

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a custom adapter (extending BaseAdapter). Items can be added to or removed from the top or bottom of the list. Items are of varying height, some much taller than others.

The behavior I'm seeing is this:

1. Scroll down to the middle of the list
2. Asynchronously, an item is added to or removed from the top of the list, calling notifyDataSetChanged()

**Desired**: Nothing changes for the user, because the data set changes only affect items that are offscreen

**Actual**: The onscreen portion of the list jumps, because all the items in it have had their position incremented or decremented, and different items are located at the old positions

How can I avoid scrambling the current view when items are changed?

It seems reasonable to me than an Adapter should be able to page through an infinite list of data, but I haven't had any luck finding examples of this in the wild. What's the right way to think about this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring that the content of the `ListView` offsets visually("the content moves up/down") when additional items are added/removed from the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Are you making use of the ViewHolder pattern?  This will do exactly what you want (not refresh the UI due to changes "off screen").

Additionally, it will make your lists much smoother and responsive.

I think this is a clear example:
http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

Comment: Can you explain further? The site you link shows how to cache calls to findViewById, but doesn't seem to address changes to the position of items in the list.

Comment: There is a pattern in Android, called the View Holder, for lists.  It is designed to 'recycle' list item views, so instead of drawing a completely new view for each item in a list, it recycles the views, which is more effecient.  This is a core pattern in creating Android lists (and will help you, in that your 'off-screen' list items, are only rendered when they come on screen, thus you won't have the problems you describe.

Comment: Regardless of ViewHolder, I think the point of an Adapter in general is to only render the Views that are onscreen.

I think the problem is that the item that used to be at position 0 is gone now. The adapter knows that position 5 is the first one onscreen, but now getItem is returning data for the item that used to be at position 6. So, the views that the user sees are for different items than before.

Comment: That is not the point of the apapter. It has absolutely nothing to do with the different elements in the list. Its point it to translate one element of data into an element of a list.  I am very confident the ViewHolder will help you.  Good luck.